# Validation in Partial view inside popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, popup

I'm working in MVC and i have one scenario as follows:
       I have a view called ManageResource where i il show the available resource's in grid and a button to add new resource. if i click on the add new resource button a popup il open with the partialview inside it, i have to display the validation result in popup itself when i click save with out entering any values and when i enter the required fields the values should be populated in the grid and the popup should be closed.`

"iam not getting validation result in popup, but can able to save data's"

following is my code:

```
Model-tblUser
public partial class tblUser
{
        public int UID { get; set; }
         [Required]
        public int EmpID { get; set; }
         [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
         [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }       
         [Required]
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }       
}

View-ManageResource
```

> ```
>          function Create() {
>
>             BootstrapDialog.show({
>             title: "Add Resource",
>             message: $('<div id="CreatePopup"></div>').load('@Url.Action("Create", "Resource")')
>            });
>             return false;
>            }
>
>     <input type="button" id="AddNewCompany" onclick="Create()" class="push_button blue btn_width"  value="Add New Resource" />
> ```

```
partial view- Create
```

> ```
>     function SaveResource() {
>
>         var obj = [];
>         var EmpID = $('#EmpID').val();
>         var FirstName = $('#FirstName').val();
>         var LastName = $('#LastName').val();        
>         var Salary = $('#Salary').val();
>         if ($("#IsActive").attr('checked', true)) {
>             var IsActive = 1;
>         }
>         else {
>             var IsActive = 0
>         }
>
>         var newrecord = {
>             "EmpID": EmpID, "FirstName": FirstName, "LastName": LastName, "Salary": Salary,   
>         };       
>         var senddata = JSON.stringify(newrecord);
>
>     jQuery.ajax({
>         type: "POST",
>         url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Resource")',
>         data: JSON.stringify({ "data": senddata }),
>         datatype: 'json',
>         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>         success: function (result) {            
>             if (result == true) {              
>                 window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ManageResource", "Resource")';
>             } else {            
>                 $("#CreatePopup").html(result);
>                 }
>             }
>         });           
>     }
> ```
>
> @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
>           {
>           @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
>
> ```
>         @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
>
>         <div class="form-group">
>             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpID, "Employee ID", new { @class = "control-label col-md-1 col-md-3" })
>             <div class="col-md-6">
>                 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmpID)
>                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpID)
>
>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="form-group">
>             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName,"First Name",  new { @class = "control-label col-md-1 col-md-3" })
>             <div class="col-md-6">
>                 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
>                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
>             </div>
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="form-group">
>             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName,"Last Name",  new { @class = "control-label col-md-1 col-md-3" })
>             <div class="col-md-6">
>                 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
>                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
>             </div>
>         </div>        
>
>         <div class="form-group">
>             <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-10">
>                 <input type="button" id="CreateResource" onclick="SaveResource()" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
>             </div>
>         </div>
>           </div>       
> }
> ```

```
   Resource Controller     

      public PartialViewResult Create(string data)   
      {             
         JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);//parsing the json data

         tblUser tbluser = new tblUser(); //creating instance for model tblUser      

            if ((string)o["EmpID"] != "" && (string)o["FirstName"] != "")// if all the required fields are present then add to db
                 {
                    db.tblUsers.Add(tbluser);//assign values here
                    tbluser.EmpID = (int)o["EmpID"];
                    tbluser.FirstName = (string)o["FirstName"];
                tbluser.FirstName = (string)o["FirstName"];
                tbluser.LastName = (string)o["LastName"];
                tbluser.EmailID = (string)o["EmailID"];
                tbluser.Password = (string)o["Password"];
                tbluser.RoleID = (int)o["RoleID"];
                tbluser.DeptID = (int)o["DeptID"];
                tbluser.DesignationID = (int)o["DesignationID"];
                tbluser.Salary = (int)o["Salary"];
                tbluser.IsActive = (bool)o["IsActive"];
                tbluser.CreatedBy = 121;
                tbluser.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                tbluser.UpdatedBy = 121;
                tbluser.UpdatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                db.SaveChanges();                       
                return RedirectToAction("ManageResource");//return to main view when saved
            }
            else
            {
               //return with validation summary to partialview popup
                 return PartialView(tbluser);
            }                   
      }
```

Comment: plz format ur question...

Answer (score 0):

When you load a form using AJAX you need to tell jQuery unobtrusive validation to add the validation `data-` properties to the form elements. You need to add: `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#YourFormSelector');`

after the `.load` is completed.

```
    function Create() {

            BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: "Add Resource",
            message: $('<div id="CreatePopup"></div>').load('@Url.Action("Create","Resource")'
            , function() {$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#YourFormSelector');})
           });
            return false;
           }
```

Comment: success: function (result) {            
            if (result == true) {              
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ManageResource", "Resource")';
            } else {            
                $("#CreatePopup").html(result);
                }
            }
        }); Even if its true the entire view is getting loaded in CreatePopup div..

Comment: Did you check if the `data-` validation attributes exist on the `input`s after the form is loaded?

Comment: I have put submit type to button and have taken javascript and instead specified in begin form where to return.. now its working perfectly.. Thanks for the feedback